# NSTableView doesn't update row height while typing in NSTextField inside a cell

Tags: swift, nstableview, nstextfield

So I have an `NSTableView` whose cells contain a self-sizing `NSTextField` with variable height. The height adjusts after I finish typing in `NSTextField` (press enter), but not during, and I need it to adjust during typing as well.

Here's the code for the self-sizing `NSTextField`:

```
override var intrinsicContentSize: NSSize {
    // Guard the cell exists and wraps
    guard let cell = self.cell, cell.wraps else {return super.intrinsicContentSize}

    // Use intrinsic width to jive with autolayout
    let width = super.intrinsicContentSize.width

    // Set the frame height to a reasonable number
    self.frame.size.height = 750.0

    // Calcuate height
    let height = cell.cellSize(forBounds: self.frame).height

    return NSMakeSize(width, height);
}

override func textDidChange(_ notification: Notification) {
    super.textDidChange(notification)
    super.invalidateIntrinsicContentSize()
}
```

The only customization for `NSTableView` is this line:

```
tableView.usesAutomaticRowHeights = true
```

[image]
[image]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does the text field resize during typing if it is not in a table view?

Comment: @Willeke No it doesn't, just checked. EDIT: after looking for an hour I literally just got found one that does work, I'll test it and get back to you.